# Getting the difference between 2 dates

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

So for example I have a string of `11/01/2021 - 15/01/2021` in cell M3. I want to make it so whenever I manually type that in, I get 4 in return (the amount of days in between those 2 dates).

Currently I'm using this formula:
`=IF(ISBLANK(M3)=FALSE, DATEDIF(TEXT(DATEVALUE(ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(SPLIT(M3, " - "), 1,1)), "dd mm yyyy"), TEXT(DATEVALUE(SUBSTITUTE(REGEXREPLACE(M3,ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(TO_TEXT(SPLIT(M3, " - ")), 1,1), "") , " - ", "")), "dd mm yyyy"), "D"),)`

Problem with that is, if the days value is bigger than 12 it just breaks and I get the error `DATEVALUE parameter '15/01/2021' cannot be parsed to date/time.`

The Locale is set to United States and the Display Language is set to English.

Any help would be much appreciated, thank you.

Comment: share a copy of your sheet

Comment: There isn't really any reason to make a whole sheet - it's literally just 1 cell to type in the value and a different cell for the formula, it doesn't depend on anything else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(DAYS(INDEX(SPLIT(M3:M, " - "),,2), 
                    INDEX(SPLIT(M3:M, " - "),,1))))
```

[image]

Comment: I recreated your spreadsheet and put in the formula but I just get blanks. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1N69ajmabf45I-W7IoekSZLadpX4g8wCs9GYy3Hy49w8/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1vBX1LoLLGBcVBz-tLiXNsMjyqaN-RTb2f1FhuPeoqok/edit#gid=0